# java remove JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

I have a frame containing a JMenuBar. If the users clicks the "Logout" MenuItem, I would remove all the frame's content and initialize it with other content. The issue is that if I call

```
parent.getContentPane().removeAll();
LoginActivity l = new LoginActivity(parent);
l.init();
parent.validate();
```

the frame gets some other content but the JMenuBar from the previous "view" it's still here.
How could I get rid of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
frame.setJMenuBar(null);  // this should do the job
```